# xstream alias from different parameter

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I try to address an advanced problem with mapping lists from my xml to my Java Objects.

I can give the problem a name: [EVE XML API](https://api.testeveonline.com/api/CallList.xml.aspx)

The link shows one problem I can't reverse engineer well: Same element tag with different content, but same attribute with different value.

It worked well to serialize objects to XML, but it can't convert back from the resulting XML to the object.

I did this mapping of my various classes:

```

```
XStream xStream = new XStream( );

// Aliases
xStream.alias("eveapi", CallList.class);
xStream.aliasAttribute(CallList.class, "version", "version");

xStream.alias("row", RowCallGroups.class);
xStream.aliasField("rowset", Result.class, "callGroups");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCallGroups.class, "groupID", "groupID");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCallGroups.class, "name", "name");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCallGroups.class, "description", "description");

xStream.addImplicitCollection(RowSetCallGroups.class, "callGroups");
xStream.alias("rowset", RowSetCallGroups.class);
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCallGroups.class, "name", "name");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCallGroups.class, "key", "key");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCallGroups.class, "columns", "columns");

xStream.alias("row", RowCalls.class);
xStream.aliasField("rowset", Result.class, "calls");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCalls.class, "accessMask", "accessMask");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCalls.class, "type", "type");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCalls.class, "name", "name");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCalls.class, "groupID", "groupID");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowCalls.class, "description", "description");

xStream.addImplicitCollection(RowSetCalls.class, "calls");
xStream.alias("rowset", RowSetCalls.class);
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCalls.class, "name", "name");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCalls.class, "key", "key");
xStream.aliasAttribute(RowSetCalls.class, "columns", "columns");
```

```

Any idea, how I can make a mapping based on the content of the `name=` attribute?

Comment: Hi, please post some more of your code so that those of us trying to read it will have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to use. In particular your data model classes (or at least the basic parts of them such as fields, package names, etc) would be helpful so that we don't have to try to reverse your code from the XML and the XStream calls.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to post a solution last night, I do that now.

First: Posting all those classes would exceed the post limit by far. D.B.

Second: The point is, I had a wrong layout of my data.

Solution: I have to use a custom converter. The "native" ones can't convert that schema.